# Managing changes from develop branch into feature prior to push (git)

Tags: git, github, merge, git-flow

Most of the teams I've worked on in the past have followed the same workflow when using Git (with some tiny variations):

1. Pull the `develop` branch (`git checkout develop`)
2. Create a new feature branch off of it (`git checkout -b feature/XYZ-123`)
3. Do your work
4. When you are ready to create a PR, add and commit your changes (`git add . && git commit -m "some commit message"`), then check `develop` back out, pull it (`git checkout develop && git pull`)
5. Switch back over to your feature branch and merge `develop` into it (`git checkout feature/XYZ-123 && git merge develop`)
6. Finally push (`git push -u origin feature/XYZ-123`) and create a PR

We'll call this the "**Merge Method**". The benefits are that any changes to `develop` since you created the branch are now merged into your branch. And so by the time you create a PR, there are no merge conflicts with `develop` and the code reviewers can see a clean, conflict-free diff between your branch and `develop`.

I am now working on a team that has a similar flow up until the merge step, but then instead of merging `develop` into my feature branch, they ask for a rebase from `origin/develop`. So the actual steps are:

1. `git checkout develop`
2. `git checkout -b feature/XYZ-123`
3. Do your work
4. `git add . && git commit -m "some commit message"`
5. `git checkout develop && git pull`
6. `git checkout feature/XYZ-123`
7. Rebase from `origin/dev`
8. `git push -u origin feature/XYZ-123`

We'll call this the "**Rebase Method**". It too produces merge conflict-free PRs, but obviously it must have different pros/cons from the Merge Method explained up above.

**I'm wondering what those pros/cons are.** What does the Merge Method lend itself to that the Rebase Method lacks, and vice versa? When should one method be used as opposed to the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but obviously it must have different pros/cons from the Merge Method explained up above

Not really. Between reverse merging (as I call it) and rebasing, it's exactly the same effect in the end, namely to try to pick up all the most recent changes from `develop` so that (1) the feature branch can be tested accurately and (2) the chances of a merge conflict when merging into `develop` are reduced.

The main visible difference between reverse merging and rebasing is the lack of the extra merge commit on the feature branch. That makes rebasing appealing. So:

- Rebasing looks a lot cleaner in the history, because you *appear* to have started the branch from a much more recent state of `develop`.

But here are some counterclaims:

- If there's an incoming conflict, rebasing makes it harder to resolve those conflicts.
- You can't rebase after pushing to form the pull request, because that rewrites shared history; whereas you can reverse merge at any time.

Personally I use both! I rebase just before the initial push to form the pull request; if the pull request lives a long time, I reverse merge periodically, and especially just before the actual approval and merge.

Comment: Thanks @matt (+1) -- I have a few followup questions if you don't mind! **(1)** does the Reverse Merge method always produce so-called "**squash commits**", and if not, what are those? **(2)** Why do you think rebasing makes it _more_ difficult to resolve merge conflicts? And **(3)** When you say "_You can't rebase after pushing to form the pull request, because that rewrites shared history_", any chance you can expand on that a little further? Maybe give an example? I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "shared history"! Thanks again!

Comment: Squash merging is totally orthogonal to this discussion and I'm not going to get into it. Rebasing makes merge conflicts harder to resolve because they can arise at various stages (commits) in the middle of the rebase, and it may not be clear how to deal with them given that there are more commits to come. Shared history is anything you've pushed that someone else might have fetched; you will have to use `force` to push a rebased version of an already pushed branch, and that is a Bad Smell that should warn you off, because you can damage the relationship of others to the data.

Comment: I appreciate your answers so much, but you pack so much information to each sentence, I feel like I could ask 10 questions for each one of your sentences here! I promise this is my last set of followups, just to lock in my high level understanding.

Comment: I must not fully understand what a rebase actually is. You make it sound as if the rebase is "replaying" all changes from the `develop` branch sequentially. If thats true, then I _think_ an example of what you're saying is: (i) I start the rebase and there are 10 commits from `develop` to merge, (ii) at Commit #4 (out of 10) there is a conflict and I merge it, (iii) at Commit #8 there is another conflict but because of how I merged the conflict at Commit 4 earlier, this manual merge at Commit #8 is made much more difficult and confusing. Is this an example of what you mean?

Comment: And second, on the rewriting shared history stuff, it sounds as if you're saying that if I try to rebase and force push my branch _after_ I create the PR, then: (i) I push those changes, (ii) another developer could merge them into `develop` by mistake while the PR is still awaiting review, (iii) the code review takes place and minor changes are requested, (iv) I make those changes in my branch and I rebase before pushing them, (v) since `develop` now mistakingly has my previous commits in it, the rebase is now replaying my prior commits over my own branch which can cause problems...

Comment: ...Is this the problem you're talking about? If so, I would think the solution is to just prevent developers from bypassing PRs and pulling feature branches into `develop` before they pass code review, right?